# How can I unroll and re_roll the matrix in numpy about specific axis?

Tags: python, numpy

(Related to a project related to neural networks)I have 500 images in the form of numpy array of shape `(500, 200, 200, 1)` that is, 500 gray scale images of dimensions (200,200). I want to unroll this into shape=`(400, 500)` where each column comes from each of the images.

Currently I am doing it as :

```
 images.shape # (500,200,200,1)    
 images = images.transpose(1,2,3,0)
 images = images.reshape(200*200*1, 500)
 images.shape # (400, 500) -- each column is an un-rolled image
```

Then in back propagation, I wan to revert back to original shape which I am doing as:

```
 D_images.shape # prints (400, 500)
 D_images = D_images.reshape(500, 200, 200, 1)
```

I suspect the reversion to original shape is not correct (I want the gradient of each example image to flow into respective example). Is there any fancier way to roll and unroll making sure examples are not mixing?

Answer (score 0):

You will have to undo both actions bottom to top with their respective complementary operations:

```
D_images = D_images.reshape(200, 200, 1, 500)
D_images = D_images.transpose(3, 0, 1, 2)
```